# Creating a file and its name using date

Tags: c

I would like to know, if we can create a file by using current date so that each day a new file is opened such as

If the date is **14 april 2013** then the file should be **140413pay.txt**

is this possible in C

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: It is possible to get the date, it is possible to concatenate, it is possible to make files.. So what do you think? And what have you tried?

Comment: [Maybe this help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425227/how-to-create-files-named-with-current-time?rq=1)

Comment: I'm trying with a normal name but need to implemet the above way.
but dont know the procedure or code.

Comment: Are you trying to create problems that `logrotate` has already solved?

Comment: Can u please give me the link where it is posted so I could check it out and know whether it resolves my issue

Comment: I would prefer `130414pay.txt` or `20130414pay.txt` as a filename. They are better in sorting and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm* t1 = localtime(&t);
    char filename[16];
    strftime (filename,9,"%d%m%Y",t1);
    strcat(filename, "pay");
    strcat(filename,".txt");
    FILE* file=fopen(filename,"a+");
    //do stuff
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how to write **pay** at the end of the file name.

Its creating a file using date but how to concatenate string with it

Comment: I've editted the answer. Now it concatenates 'pay' to the filename.

Comment: it worked..

but if we have created a file and now we want to add detail to the file than we have to use all the codes above but replace the "W" with "A+"

Comment: It can be just "a+", the file will be created if it does not exist.

Comment: what procedure to use while edditing the file when called from another function

Comment: ITYM `strftime(filename, sizeof filename, "%d%m%Ypay.txt", t1);`